# PHP FILTER_VALIDATE_INT issue

Tags: php

I had issue about FILTER_VALIDATE_INT function when i put 0 as entry value it show 'error' instead of 'ok':

```
$delivery = 0;
if (filter_var($delivery,FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) {
    echo 'ok';
}else{
    echo 'error';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Compare with false, because PHP consider zero returning  as false

```
if (false !== filter_var($delivery,FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) {
```

Answer (score 2):

Check for strict type check it will work,

```
$delivery = 0;
if (filter_var($delivery,FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) !== false) {
    echo 'ok';
}else{
    echo 'error';
}
```

**[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a0facf7c899ddc2f45115fa170ff238d83e8c391)**